# How to convert single array to multidimensional and group base on value name

Tags: php

for some reason i find hard to do single array to multidimensional

Im looking to group same filter_group_id with their filters like that

if filter_group_id is same as previews do

array[0][group_name] = > group_name, filter_group_id

then put all filters for same group in array like this

array[0][filters][] = > name, filter_id

for example i have single array like this one

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [filter_group_id] => 43
        [group_name] => price
        [filter_id] => 62
        [name] => 10 - 50 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [filter_group_id] => 43
        [group_name] => price
        [filter_id] => 64
        [name] => 100 - 150 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [filter_group_id] => 33
        [group_name] => size
        [filter_id] => 52
        [name] => 20m
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [filter_group_id] => 33
        [group_name] => size
        [filter_id] => 51
        [name] => 10m
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [filter_group_id] => 32
        [group_name] => color
        [filter_id] => 49
        [name] => red
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [filter_group_id] => 31
        [group_name] => height
        [filter_id] => 44
        [name] => 90
    )

)
```

and i like to become like this one

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [group_name] => Array
            (
                [name] => price
                [filter_group_id] => 43
            )

        [filters] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [filter_id] => 62
                        [name] => 10 - 50
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [filter_id] => 63
                        [name] => 50 - 100
                    )
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [group_name] => Array
            (
                [name] => size
                [filter_group_id] => 33
            )

        [filters] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [filter_id] => 52
                        [name] => 20m
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [filter_id] => 51
                        [name] => 10m
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [group_name] => Array
            (
                [name] => color
                [filter_group_id] => 32
            )

        [filters] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [filter_id] => 49
                        [name] => red
                    )
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [group_name] => Array
            (
                [name] => height
                [filter_group_id] => 31
            )

        [filters] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [filter_id] => 46
                        [name] => 90
                    )
            )

    )
)
```

What i tried is this but thie coming in separaated arrays

```
    $new_name = '';
    $old_name = '';
    $i = 0;

        foreach ($query->rows as $key => $value) {

        $new_name = $value['group_name'];
        if ($new_name != $old_name) {
            $data[$i] = array(
                'group_name'    => array(
                    'name'  => $value['group_name'],
                    'filter_group_id'   => $value['filter_group_id']
                ),
                'filters'   => array(
                    'name'  => $value['name'],
                    'filter_id' => $value['filter_id']
                )
            );

            $i++;
        }else {
            $data[$i] = array(
                'group_name'    => array(
                    'name'  => $value['group_name'],
                    'filter_group_id'   => $value['filter_group_id']
                ),
                'filters'   => array(
                    'name'  => $value['name'],
                    'filter_id' => $value['filter_id']
                )
            );
            
        }

        $old_name = $value['group_name'];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to group your array based on the `group_name` and `filter_group_id` values, making a key for the result array based on those two values and adding the matching filter values to the `filters` subarray for each key. You can then use [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to re-index the result array numerically:

```
$result = array_reduce($data, function ($c, $v) {
    $key = $v['group_name'] . '#' . $v['filter_group_id'];
    if (!isset($c[$key])) {
        $c[$key] = array('group_name' => array('group_name' => $v['group_name'], 'filter_group_id' => $v['filter_group_id']));

    }
    $c[$key]['filters'][] = array('filter_id' => $v['filter_id'], 'name' => $v['name']);
    return $c;
}, array());

$result = array_values($result);
print_r($result);
```

The output is too long to show here but matches your requirement.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/adWAs)

Comment: almost what im looking for , how can change the group_name to be name of the array and than inside to be name and filter_group_id  ?

Comment: @Ivan sorry, didn't pay quite enough attention to my output. I've updated the answer and the demo